# Plugin "Add from server" not working when selection a large number of medias

Tags: plugins

I am migrating my website to wordpress and I have the images organized in folders like wp. I already uploaded the folders and files into wp-content/uploads.
I try using "Add from server" plugin to add the images to the library, but noting happen when I select a large number at ones.
Is there any chance to get it work ? Or suggest another plugin that does the job.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Add From Server Plugin no longer works for the current version of WordPress. The Media Sync plugin works (as shown above) or use - [WP-CLI Media Imports](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/)

There is a pretty awesome article I found - [Bulk Upload WordPress Media](https://managewp.com/blog/bulk-upload-wordpress-media-library-ftp)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can try "Media Sync": https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the plugins website (https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) it's **NOT meant** to be used **for migrations or bulk uploads** but to add a small number of files that exceed the maximum allowed upload file size.

> Please Note: This plugin is not designed to replace the media uploader. This plugin is not designed to be used for migration of sites. This plugin is not designed to re-import your media upload history. This plugin is not designed to Batch import your media. Etc. This plugin is 8 years old and designed for importing singular large files which could not be uploaded through the administration interface.

I assume the script reaches the PHP *max_execution_time*. So, if you are still determined to use this plugin to accomplish the task, increasing it most likely will solve the issue.

As an alternative, you may want to try the **Media from FTP** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/) plugin as it's using AJAX and therefore won't cause any timeouts.